# Android webview does not load CSS properly

Tags: android, css, caching, webview

On app start, i cache an url with a webview (which i do not add to layout to make it invisible to the user) like this:

```
public void doOfflineCaching (final Context context) {

    final WebView w = new WebView(context);
    BaseWebView.setDefaultSettings(w.getSettings(), context);      
    w.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){

           getLogger().debug("caching(" + url + ") ...");
           super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

           getLogger().debug("caching(" + url + ") ... finished");
           super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        }});
   w.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient ());

   String url =  BaseClass.getInstance().buildBaseUrl(context.getResources().getString(R.string.bib_url));
   w.loadUrl(url);

}
```

BaseWebView.java:

```
public static void setDefaultSettings(WebSettings settings, Context context) {

    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

    settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);

    settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    settings.setGeolocationDatabasePath("/data/data/fcmsWebapp");

    settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    settings.setAppCachePath(context.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());

    settings.setUserAgentString(UserAgent.getInstance().getUserAgent());
 }
```

If the app is offline, i load the cached url in the 'Main Webview' with the following cache mode:

```
getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY);
```

The 'Main Webview' does load the setDefaultSettings-method, too. And a WebChromeclient/WebViewClient is also set.

The first load of the cached url works as expected:

[image]

But if i reload the url, it looks like this:

[image]

After reload the site is fine again, next reload it is broke and so on...

Tested on Nexus 10 / Android 5.1
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You need to check cache-related response headers for subresources. For example, I've glanced at the mobile version of "Neue Luzerner Zeitung", and the "cache-control" header for some of its resources is set to "max-age=1200", that is 1200 seconds = 20 minutes. Which means, they will need to be reloaded from network in 20 minutes. It is possible that for some resources it can be set to "no-cache". It's hard to do offline caching of sites for which you have no complete control this way.

Comment: @A.D. Did you get any solution to this? I am facing the same problem.